# Is this piecewise function Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: riemann-integration

How to check if function is a Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$? I don't know how to find lower and upper Darboux sum.

$$f(x) =\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1,\text{when}\  \exists \ m,n \in \mathbb{N}, x = \frac{m}{2^n}\\
                  0, \text{otherwise}
                \end{array}
              \right.$$

Comment: Do you mean $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Sorry, i meant $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Take any subinterval of $[0,1]$. It contains a number of the form $m/2^n$ (just take any $n$ so that the length of the interval is smaller than $2^{-n}$). It also contains a number not of that form, e.g. any irrational number. That means that the supremum of $f$ on any interval is 1, and the infimum is 0.